# Shopping Cart Increment / Decrment Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

```
<div class="custom-qty">
        <div class="qty-ctl">
                <button title="Decrease Qty" onclick="changeQty('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',0); return false;" class="decrease"><?php echo $this->__('-') ?></button>
            </div>
            <input id="<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"  readonly/>
            <div class="qty-ct2">
                <button title="Increase Qty" onclick="changeQty('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',1); return false;" class="increase"><?php echo $this->__('+') ?></button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**Js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function changeQty(id,increase) {
          var qty = parseInt($(id).value);
           if ( !isNaN(qty) ) {
                qty = increase ? qty+1 : (qty>1 ? qty-1 : 1);
                $(id).value = qty;
                document.getElementById("scart").submit();
            }
    }
</script>
```

**error**

```
changeQty not defined
```

I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onclick attribute use this

```
return changeQty('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',1)
```

and in js call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function changeQty(id,increase) {
          var qty = parseInt(jQuery(id).value);
           if ( !isNaN(qty) ) {
                qty = increase ? qty+1 : (qty>1 ? qty-1 : 1);
                jQuery(id).value = qty;
                document.getElementById("scart").submit();
            }

return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Hope this help you**

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Just remove `$` with `jQuery`! check my updated answer

Comment: No luck still same

Comment: are you sure that this function is exits on the same page?? Also did you cleared your browser cache??

Comment: I am not able to find your js function on the page. So make sure that you include the function on page

Comment: Sorry it's working fine i added custom header that's the problem \

Comment: @MagentoDev please delete the site name you posted in above comment : beta - stylebaby-com , otherwise google will scrawl our site in this link.